# Android bitmap to ByteArray and vice versa returns null?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, buffer

I am trying to allocate direct bytebuffer from java, fill it from bitmap and create bitmap from that buffer. But as a result I receive null.

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    mCurrentBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(hardCodedPath, options);

    // 4 - bytes count per pixel
    bytesCount = mCurrentBitmap.getWidth() * mCurrentBitmap.getHeight() * 4;

    pixels = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((int) bytesCount);
    mCurrentBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(this.pixels);

    byte[] bitmapdata = new byte[pixels.remaining()];
    pixels.get(bitmapdata);

    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

    Bitmap newBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata, 0, (int) bytesCount, opt);
```

Can someone help me to understand why the newBitmap is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decodeByteArray()` expects encoded Bitmap data (PNG, JPEG, etc.), not a simple RGB(A) byte array. To do what you want you can simply use `Bitmap.setPixels()`. First, create a Bitmap of the right size/configuration (`Bitmap.create(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)` for instance) then call `setPixels(bitmapdata, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height)` on it.

Since you have a `ByteBuffer` you can do it even more easily by calling `Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer()`. Just like with `setPixels()`, create a Bitmap of the right size first.